# How to abort a payment request in RMStore?

Tags: swift

I want to use RMStore to implement my in-app purchase. The method `[RMStore addPayment]` sends a payment request, but I want to confirm the product is well delivered, and abort the payment if not.
Question is: where should I put my handling code, and how can I abort the payment?

Comment: (Assuming that you mean "abort", as in "cancel"). I believe the transactions don't work that way - once payment has been verified, unfinished transactions "remain in the queue until they’re finished, and the transaction queue observer is called every time your app is launched" (Apple's guide).

Comment: So once payment has been verified, there's no way to cancel it at all, right?What could I do to make sure user got the product delivery?

Comment: Do you have an in-app purchase that isn't for your app but for something else? Is that even possible?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not my point.Here is what I mean. assume user have paid for it, usually my server would give the product to user. But I'm afraid there may be some error occured, so the user may not recieve my product(server unstateble or something). If that happened I wanna cancel the transaction.